# Collapse UIImageview in UITableview cell, when it doesn't return an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, sdwebimage

**Summary of the problem**

I have a UITableView in which I want to Collapse it's UIImageView cell part, whenever it doesn't return an image, as seen below

***first image of tableview cell*** (the expected result)

[image: The correct form]
 ***second image of tableview cell*** (the no image result)

[image: No image form]

**Background including what I've already tried**

Below is the piece of code that I have been working on. Also notice that I'm using SDWebImage to get and set the image in the app (any method in tableview delegates, SDWebImage protocols etc that I'm missing just point me),

> The comment out part is what I have done, i.e. used constraints to try
>   the collapse of UIimageView not it messes up the whole tableView upon
>   scrolling

**Code**

Here is piece of code I'm working on,

```
[cell.i_imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: item.PostimageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {

        if(!image)
        {
                    //cell.i_imageView.hidden = YES;

            NSLog(@"why no image des:%@",error);
            NSLog(@"why no image url:%@",imageURL);
        }

//            cell.imageHolderAspectConstraint.active = TRUE;
//            cell.imageHolderZeroImageConstraint.active = FALSE;
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            cell.imageHolderAspectConstraint.active = FALSE;
//            cell.imageHolderZeroImageConstraint.active = TRUE ;
//
//            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
//            [cell setNeedsLayout];
//        }

        [cell.i_imageView sd_removeActivityIndicator];

    }];
```

Any help in this matter is highly appreciated, cheers.

**Edit**

Here is the image of storyboard section, where do I need to embed stackview

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `ImageView` in `StackView`. Now hide your ImageView when image is not available.

**Note :** UIStackView automatically handle height of cell.

> Edit:

As of now your UI is something like this.

[image]

Now select your image holding view and click on embedded in and select UIStackView.

[image]

Now assign the same constraints that you have given to holding view to stackView.

Now your hierarchy is like below

[image]

Finally you need to do below code in CellForRow:

```
cell.vImageHoldingView.hidden = !image;
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely reply can you look at the edited part of the question

Comment: @HamzaIqbal What is vImage Holding View ?

Comment: It has the required ImageView that needs to be collapsed

Comment: @HamzaIqbal I am seeing three dots (more option) , where it is? I think you need to hide that too.

Comment: This is comes under the accepted solution bracket, but here the conflicting matter was only UIImageView, which was addressed in the accepted solution

Comment: The accepted solution embedded UIImageView only, which was needed because that is the only part of the table cell I want to collapse only

Comment: But where to hide it though ;( -- "Finally you need to do below code in CellForRow:"

Comment: I have produced all the steps you advised, but now I have collapsing of the imageView is not taking place, still need help

Comment: @HamzaIqbal What happened , where you were stucked now?

Comment: Fixed it, was missing various constraints for other elements in cell, thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Embed if in a stackView
- Attach stackview anchors to the desired anchors
- Hide image view if needed.

[image]

StackView automatically collapses its hidden `arrangedSubViews`

**Note:** If you set the image `nil`, it will collapse again, because stackView manages imageView height according to its image.

Comment: Thanks for the timely reply can you look at the edited part of the question

Comment: Answer is the same @HamzaIqbal. You just need to match anchors of the stackView to the correct anchors. Probably **vImageHoldingView**

Comment: I added an image. You probably need to add 0 for all sides of the stackView. And the button has its own constraints.

Comment: It does not do "StackView automatically collapses its hidden arrangedSubViews", where do I need to call hide property?

Comment: imageView.isHidden = true

Comment: This pops up "No setter method 'setIsHidden:' for assignment to property"

Answer (score -2):

If there is no image, make the `ImageView` height to `0`. Remaining things will get handled if it has a proper constraints.

Answer (score -2):

make picture bottom constraint as outlet . Like this

```
var bottomViewConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and give value on collapse and expand. like this

```
bottomViewConstraints.constant = 0 // expand 
bottomViewConstraints.constant = 60 // collapse
```

Comment: Perhaps, elaborate?

Comment: You have image outlet , in your swift file . and in Xib file this image must have height Constratraint.                                                                                                      var heightConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!                                                                                  heightConstraints.constant = 0 // expand       When you give constant = 0 if will hide your image view . (Which Seem like your requirments)
    heightConstraints.constant = 60 // collapse